# Merge inequalities into one

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm

Suppose that I have been given n inequalities as follows:

**Input:**

Example : n=4

```
f4 > f2 > f3
f4 > f1 > f3
f4 > f2 > f1
f2 > f1 > f3
```

**Output:**

I have to merge these inequalities to make 1 inequality such that the above inequalities stay true. For the example above:

```
f4 > f2 > f1 > f3
```

There can be multiple inequalities as answer; I need any one that is correct. It is also sure that there exists a solution for the given inputs; that is, we can assume that the inputs will always be valid.

Any ideas on how to make an algorithm to implement this?

I have been thinking that directed graphs can be used for this, but I am not sure.

Any ideas to implement the above algorithm? The value of n can be very large.

Comment: A directed graph would certainly be a viable way to represent these inequalities.

Answer (score 2):

This solution extracts all two-item inequalities and performs a sort that obeys them:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ineq = """f4 > f2 > f3
f4 > f1 > f3
f4 > f2 > f1
f2 > f1 > f3"""
>>> print(ineq)
f4 > f2 > f3
f4 > f1 > f3
f4 > f2 > f1
f2 > f1 > f3
>>> greater_thans, all_f = set(), set()
>>> for line in ineq.split('\n'):
    tokens = line.strip().split()[::2]
    for n, t1 in enumerate(tokens[:-1]):
        for t2 in tokens[n+1:]:
            greater_thans.add((t1, t2))
            all_f.add(t1)
        all_f.add(t2)


>>> sorted(all_f, cmp=lambda t1, t2: 0 if t1==t2 else (1 if (t1, t2) not in greater_thans else -1))
['f4', 'f2', 'f1', 'f3']
>>>
```

Kind guys on group [comp.lang.python](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.python/uoswjUBBtgI/Gm6AUvduuQcJ) pointed out that if the original set of relations did not include *every* less-than relation then the sort might fail so I needed to add a function `expand_transitive_relations`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import permutations


def extract_relations(ineq):
    "Turns lines of lists of relations separated by '>' into set of tuples of (x,y) pairs where x > y"
    greater_thans, all_f = set(), set()
    for line in ineq.split('\n'):
        tokens = line.strip().split()[::2]
        for n, t1 in enumerate(tokens[:-1]):
            for t2 in tokens[n+1:]:
                greater_thans.add((t1, t2))
                all_f.add(t1)
            all_f.add(t2)
    expanded = expand_transitive_ralations(greater_thans, all_f)
    return sorted(all_f, cmp=lambda t1, t2: 0 if t1==t2 else 
                                            (1 if (t1, t2) not in expanded else -1))

def expand_transitive_ralations(greater_thans, all_f):
    "if x > y and y > z then x > z"
    start_len = len(greater_thans)
    while True:
        for x, y, z in permutations(all_f, 3):
            if (x, y) in greater_thans and (y, z) in greater_thans:
                greater_thans.add((x, z))
        new_len = len(greater_thans)
        if start_len == new_len:
            break
        else:
            start_len = new_len
    return greater_thans

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for ineq in (
            """\
            f4 > f2 > f3
            f4 > f1 > f3
            f4 > f2 > f1
            f2 > f1 > f3\
            """,
            """\
            f4 > f2 > f3 
            f4 > f1 > f3 
            f4 > f2 > f1 
            f2 > f1 > f3 
            f3 > f5\
            """,
            """\
            f2 > f3 
            f3 > f1\
            """):
        print(ineq)
        print('  Becomes:', ' > '.join(extract_relations(ineq)), '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
            f4 > f2 > f3
            f4 > f1 > f3
            f4 > f2 > f1
            f2 > f1 > f3            
  Becomes: f4 > f2 > f1 > f3 

            f4 > f2 > f3 
            f4 > f1 > f3 
            f4 > f2 > f1 
            f2 > f1 > f3 
            f3 > f5            
  Becomes: f4 > f2 > f1 > f3 > f5 

            f2 > f3 
            f3 > f1            
  Becomes: f2 > f3 > f1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a directed graph, in which vertices will be given variables and edges will be between bigger and smaller (connection `v1 --> v2` means `v1 > v2`). For example:

```
f4 > f2 > f3
f4 > f1 > f3
f4 > f2 > f1
f2 > f1 > f3
```

means edges are from `f4` to `f2 & f1`, from `f2` to `f3 & f1` and from `f1` to `f3`. `f3` has no outgoing edges.

Now you can just [sort topologically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) graph. Pay attention, if you have a cycle there is no solution! `f4 -> f2 -> f1 -> f4` means `f4 > f2 > f1 > f4`.

Comment: Why did you select only these 2 to make edge?

Comment: @Jerky It was just an another example. However, I edited my post and described yours example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use topological sort on a directed graph that represents these inequalities. It can be done in O(N + M) time using depth-first search(where N is the number of variables and M is the number of inequalities).

Answer (score 0):

An approach that could work is to make a directed graph G in which an edge u to v represents that u > v (naturally, every inequality corresponds to an edge in G), look for a vertex w with no incoming edges and then try to find a non-cyclic path with n vertices, starting at w. This is merely intuition, though; it could be erroneous and to me there's no obvious similarity to Tacet's and user2040251's topological sort proposals.

**Edit**
It looks like my suggestion involves topological sort too, but maybe the specifics differ somewhat between our suggestions?